# convert unix timestamp in filename

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, unix-timestamp

I use MacOSX Lion but I'm also happy with solution for Windows as I have Windows XP in a virtual machine:

I have hundreds of files with a unix timestamp in the filename, like this:

```
1341131403_-_db123456.sql.gz
1341390599_-_db123456.sql.gz
1341563401_-_db123456.sql.gz
```

And I want to have the timestamps converted to readable timestamps and the files to be renamed with that readable timestamp, like this:

```
2012-07-01 08-30-03.sql.gz
2012-07-04 08-29-59.sql.gz
2012-07-06 08-30-01.sql.gz
```

I have spent several hours on an applescript solution, but with no success:

```
on open (the_input)
tell application "Finder"
set the_files to every item of the_input
set the_count to count of the_files
repeat with i from 1 to the_count
set current_file to item i of the_files
set old_name to (name of current_file) as string
set old_name to trim_line(old_name, "_-_db123456. sql. gz", 1)
set new_name to (result of uts_convert(old_name)) as string
set the name of current_file to (new_name & file type of current_file)
end repeat
end tell
end open

on uts_convert(input)
set shellcommand1 to "date -r "
set shellcommand2 to " \"+%Y-%m-%d %H-%M\""
set the_output to do shell script (shellcommand1 & input & shellcommand2)
return the_output
end uts_convert
```

Any help is appreciated! I dont care if it is done with applescript or a simple terminal command or whatever.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "Finder" to set theFiles to every file of folder ((path to desktop) & "testfolder" as text)
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, "_-_"}
repeat with aFile in theFiles
    set timestamp to text item 1 of (name of aFile as text)
    set newName to do shell script "date -r " & timestamp & " '+%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S'"
    set aFile's name to (newName & ".sql.gz")
end repeat
set text item delimiters to TID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple Perl solution:

```
opendir($dir, ".");
while ($f = readdir($dir)) {
    if ($f =~ m/^(\d+)_-_db\d+\.sql\.gz/) {
        ($s, $i, $h, $d, $m, $y) = gmtime($1);
        rename($f, sprintf("%4d-%02d-%02d %02d-%02d-%02d.sql.gz", $y + 1900, $m + 1, $d, $h, $i, $s));
    }
}
closedir($dir);
```

Save that into renamethings.pl or whatever you want in the same folder as the files and run:

```
perl renamethings.pl
```

It would probably be prudent to make a backup of the files first just in case something goes awry.

Comment: Your sprintf is far neater as   strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S", gmtime($1)). use POSIX 'strftime' for it.